# Can we assign ng-model to span?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to assign the value to span based on the selected answer in dropdown.

[image: screenshot]

```
<tr class="tableheightQues" ng-repeat="question in questionnaireData track by $index">
<td>{{$index + 1}}) </td>
<td style="width:50%;"><span class="" title="{{question.QuestionItem}}">{{question.QuestionItem}}</span> </td>
<td>
    <div class="">
        <select ng-if="question.MasterDataCategoryId != null"
                id="answer{{question.QuestionId}}"
                ng-model="question.MasterData"
                ng-init="question.MasterData" class="form-control"
                style="width: 300px; white-space:pre-wrap;">
            <option ng-repeat="answer in answerData[question.MasterDataCategoryId]"
                    value="{{answer.MasterData}}">
              {{answer.MasterData}}
            </option>
        </select>
        <input ng-if="question.MasterDataCategoryId == null" 
               id="{{question.QuestionId}}" ng-model="question.MasterData"
               type="text" style="width: 300px;" name="question.QuestionId"
               class="form-control">
        <!--<span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && formVHD.$valid"></span>-->
    </div>
</td>
```

```
<td>
    <div class=""> 
      <span ng-if="question.MasterDataCategoryId != null"
            ng-repeat="answer in answerData[question.MasterDataCategoryId] | filter : question.MasterData : true">
        <span ng-if="question.MasterData" ng-model="question.Score">
        {{answer.Score}}
        </span>
        <span ng-if="!question.MasterData"> </span>
      </span>
      <select ng-if="question.MasterDataCategoryId == null"
              id="projectlist" class="form-control"
              required ng-model="question.Score">
            <option selected="selected"></option>
            <option ng-repeat="score in scoringDetails"
                    value="{{score.Score}}"> {{score.Score}}
            </option>
      </select>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Above is the code I have used.

How to assign `ng-model` to span show get the data while saving all information?

Comment: try use `ng-bind`

Comment: @Dean ng-bind wont help to get data back I guess.

Comment: `ng-model="data"` or `{{data}}` is a two-way data-binding, you usually want them on **input**, **textarea** or **select**. Try using `ng-bind="data"` or `{{::data}}` instead

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "span based on the selected answer in dropdown" ? Are you looking for a conditional statement?

Comment: @Vivz in the screenshot you can see score right that value I need to assign it to send it to API.

Comment: You can get that value from ng-model="question.Score" . Right?

Comment: @Vivz I tried it I am not able to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

ng-model directives are only for input elements.You can use ng-bind instead

```
<span ng-if="question.MasterData" ng-bind="question.Score">
```

or use curly braces

```
<span ng-if="question.MasterData">{{question.Score}}</span>
```

Find more about directives [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)